# How do I remove the top sash of a medium size new double glazed window?

Tags: windows, cleaning

How do I remove the top sash of my new double glazed window to wash the outside (while remaining inside the house). I was able to lift the bottom and lean it inside the room and thoroughly clean it then push it back into place. I can not see how to pull the top section inside to wash it. (not possible to wash it outside, prickly bushes and I wouldn't know how to remove the tall screen).

Comment: call the manufacture

Answer (score 1):

**Find the Mechanism**
There is usually a release mechanism along the top edge or the bottom edge of the upper sash that allows it to tilt in.

**Get the Lower Sash out of the Way**
The trick is moving the inner, lower sash out of the way.  That is done by releasing the mechanism on the lower sash, tilting it inward and lowering it toward the sill.

**Tilt the Upper Sash in**
You then slightly lower the top sash, which is no longer blocked by the lower sash.  You can then release the mechanism on the top sash and tilt it inward, either up or down depending on the position of the mechanism.